# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) in django

Tags: python, django

i am making an app in django. this is my index.html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>The index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Choose the name of student</h1>
    <form action= "{% url 'detail' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
            <select name="namedrop">
                {% for name in student_list %}
                <option>{{name.stuname}}</option>
                {% endfor %}

            </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

it creates a drop down list of the name of students. when i select one and click on submit button, it opens a new page detail but fails to show anything on the page. the error it is showing is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED).
my views.py is as below:

```
from .models import student,subject
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name= 'studinfo/index.html'
    context_object_name= 'student_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return student.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model=  student,subject
    template_name='studinfo/detail.html'


def getname(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        name=request.get['namedrop']
        return render(request, 'detail.html', {'name':name})
```

this is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .models import student

urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^detail/$',views.DetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),

]


from .models import student
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render



class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name= 'studinfo/index.html'
    context_object_name= 'student_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return student.objects.all()

def detail(request,student_id):
    try:

        p = student.objects.get(pk=student_id)
    except student.DoesNotExist:

        raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
    return render(request, 'studinfo/detail.html', {'name': p})
```

this is my view now..now it is raising an error ..TypeError at /studinfo/detail/
detail() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
Request Method: POST
500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: `please help soon` . Don't try to include these phrases into your question. I edited the question to remove that part

Comment: include your urls.py in the question. Include the full traceback of the error you are receiving

Comment: Show your `urls.py`. Are you using `getname` at all? If you are using the `DetailView` it can't process POST requests.

Comment: from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .models import student

urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^detail/$',views.DetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),

]

Comment: @PauloAlmeida why can't it process post requests with detailview?it does in the case of form class

Comment: @Shefali In addition to Arpit's answer, I'm not sure about what you're trying to accomplish. Why not just have links for the students, instead of a form? In that case you can use the `DetailView` and the interface will be simpler. Of course, it may not be what you want if you plan to add other things.

Comment: @Shefali See the link in Arpit's answer. `DetailView` doesn't have all those form processing methods and attributes, like form classes.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida i have to make a drop down menu and pass the selected option to the details page where the details of students can be seen...but its just not happening. and yes i did saw the link..you were right. but still another error is there..

Comment: @Shefali Ok, sorry, I hadn't realized you were using a dropdown. For your current problem: your view takes the parameter `student_id`, but you are not passing it in the URL. You would have to pass it as a named group in the `detail` url. See [the section about views in the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views) for details. But you want to pass the `student_id` in the form anyway, what you need to do is remove `student_id` from the `detail` function's parameters and process it later (similar to what you were doing in `getname` actually).

Comment: def detail(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        name=request.GET['namedrop']
        return render(request, 'detail.html', {'name':name})                                   but now it shows MultiValueDictKeyError at /studinfo/detail/
"'namedrop'"  any idea why? @PauloAlmeida

Comment: @Shefali This is getting a bit confusing and I think Arpit is right, you should ask a different question instead of expanding the scope of this one, which is already answered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`DetailView` can not process post requests. `DetailView` only allows get requests. 405 method not allowed error is raised when you are using a wrong request method since it does not allow post request it it raising 405 error.

I see that you have a `getname` view. I think you were trying to use that. If not that then you have to change your `url` to a view that accepts post requests. More on `DetailView` can be read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)

Comment: You have to ask another question for this.  Don't edit the question like this otherwise it will go beyond its original scope. I suggest ask another question. People will be happy to help you there.

Comment: I use **View**, not **DetailView**, what is the difference. I was trying to use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54283074/creating-update-or-create-form-view-in-django

Comment: I changed it to a **FormView** and the error went away.