# Creating update or create form view in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model named `profile` and it has a one to one relationship with the `User` model. `profile` contains unnecessary information about the user like bio, gender, country, etc. So when the user signs up, they won't have a profile yet. When the user goes into settings and starts entering details, then they will have a profile.

That being said, how do I create a view in Django that can both create profile details about the user or update existing information.

**Form**

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar', 'bio', 'gender', 'dob', 'country']
```

**View**

```
class SettingsView(FormView):
    template_name = 'oauth/settings.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('oauth:settings')
    redirect_field_name = "next"
```

Comment: Should user be logged in to go to settings page ?

Comment: @Ahtisham Yes they should

Comment: If you have any query let me know ☺️

Comment: @Ahtisham Thank you, i'll try to implement your method soon, but do you think some code can be removed if we used the update_or_create method?

Comment: Yes we can. I edit the answer check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.views import View
from .forms import ProfileForm
from .models import Profile

class Settings(View):
   form_class = ProfileForm
   template_name = 'oauth/settings.html'

   def post(self, request):
      form = self.form_class(request.POST)
      data = {'error':''}
      if form.is_valid():
          user = request.user
          bio = form.cleaned_data['bio']
          # more fields here
          try:
             profile = user.profile
             # update user profile
             profile.bio = bio
             # add more fields here
             profile.save()
             data['response'] = 'profile updated!'
          except:
             profile = Profile(user=user,bio=bio) #add more fields
             profile.save()
             data['response'] = 'profile created!'
     else:
        data['error'] = 'Invalid form!'
     return render(request, self.template_name,{'data':data})
```

**Edit:**

Or we can use `update_or_create()` as suggested by the OP in comments.

By replacing `try` and `except` blocks with:

```
updated_values = {'bio':bio} # add more fields
obj, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(user=user,bio=bio, defaults=updated_values) # add more fields
if created:
   data['response'] = 'profile created!'
else:
   data['response'] = 'profile updated!'
```

Comment: I removed checking for existing of user in database as that was unnecessary.

Comment: This works perfectly! However, is there a way to populate the form with the user values if they already have a profile?

Comment: If that helped you then you can mark it as accepted. And yes but that should be asked as a saperate question.

Comment: Sure, just one question related to this question here: For return `render(request, template_name,{'data':data})` `template_name` does not exist. How can I refer to itself?

Comment: Try `self.template_name`

Comment: I get this error: `Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: POST '/settings/'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: POST '/settings/'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` However, I replaced it with:  `return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)` and it works fine

Comment: Remove `oauth/` in  `template_name` variable.